# Binding ng-model to ng-options selection

Tags: angularjs, html-select, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I am having difficulty binding a selection to ng-model from a select box built with ng-options.  Ultimately, I want to include a number of select boxes which act as cascading filters, built dynamically from an array

Here's what I've got - and the issue is 'loc' isn't getting the selected option from the select box.

```
            <th class="col-sm-1">Location
                    <select class="form-control input-sm" name="aws_child_loc_stat" ng-model="loc" ng-options="loc as aws.child_loc_stat for aws in aws | unique: 'child_loc_stat'">
                    </select></th>
```

Plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/lhRl1GMxnNeD8qUO0HNm

Answer (score 1):

Your `ngModel` is the same your `value` defined attribute in the `ngOptions` - which is bad. Make your `ngModel` something different:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="aws_child_loc_stat" ng-model="selectedLoc" ng-options="loc as aws.child_loc_stat for aws in aws | unique: 'child_loc_stat'">
```

Comment: That isn't working.  Plunk is updated.  Am I missing something?